# JavaScript/jQuery in ASP .NET MVC layout page not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, alert

JavaScript is enabled in the Chrome browser. I want an alert to appear when a paragraph is clicked. WHY is it not working?!
If I had got the JavaScript working I assume the jQuery would also work.

Here is the _Layout.cshtml page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

    <script>
        $(document).ready(
            $("#para").click(function() {
                alert("you clicked the paragraph");
            })
        );
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="para">Some paragraph</p>

 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
 @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(
        $("#para").click(function() {
            alert("you clicked the paragraph");
        })
    );
```

Should be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//                ^^^^^^^^^^^  <<<<--------------------------------
    $("#para").click(function() {
        alert("you clicked the paragraph");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You have included jquery twice. Once in the head section and once at the end. Try like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <p id="para">Some paragraph</p>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#para").click(function() {
            alert("you clicked the paragraph");
        });
    </script>
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

The `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` call uses ASP.NET MVC 4 new bundling mechanism which is including jQuery. Look at your `~/App_Start/BundleConfig.cs` file to see how this is configured. Also notice how in my example I have removed the `document.ready` call because it is no longer necessary since I have placed the script at the end of the document.

Comment: How many times he included jQuery doesn't matter, the wrong syntax does.

Comment: It might not matter in this case but failing to understand the what the code does might be problematic in the future when it will matter. I agree with you that the wrong syntax is the problem in this case but as you can see from my answer the proper place to put the script is at the end of the document where you don't even need to use a `document.ready` call.

Comment: thanks, will note that. I wasn't 100% sure what that bundle thing was that's why I included it again.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.